# How to diagnose error 400, bad request, after upgrading Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers, 400

I'm the author of an open-source [client-server application](http://www.lightandmatter.com/ogr/ogr.html) that seems to have stopped working on my own server after I upgraded to Apache 2.2.22. I now get http error 400, bad request, on all my client's POST requests. I get nothing in the apache error log, even though my LogLevel is currently set to "warn." A typical request looks like this:

```
POST /cgi-bin/spotter3/ServerOG.cgi HTTP/1.0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: OpenGrade
Content-Length: 143

/1EaFTX2Ae8yoveeee3pogKMumU
class=s2017/223
user=bcrowell
get_what=roster
client_date=2017-5-24 21:17:49
what=get_class_data
account=bcrowell
```

Is there a good way to diagnose this problem? Can I change something in my apache configuration file so that something informative will be written to my access log in this situation? Is there a "lint"-style utility for HTTP headers, or a parser that gives good errors and warnings? Is there anything about this request that looks like it would be archaic or deprecated?

Comment: I think the problem was that I was using \n as a line terminator rather than \r\n. Apparently older versions of Apache tolerated this, but newer ones don't.

Answer (score 0):

First thing we can change the log level here to warn in the httpd.conf , Then we can check the error_log file in the apache there we will be able to find valuable information once we hit the url